# Activity transition from recyclerview Item to other activity with shared elements is not smooth

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm trying to animate animate the transition from a recyclerview item to an activity with details about that item. I've followed this example:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions

The activities both use shared view elements. The transitions are working, but not as smooth as I would expect. What I mean by that is during the transition, the text shortly falls outside the cardview and the image snaps back in place. See the video:

[Video exmaple](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOR59LD7KaGutGeN0P6-LLUv3TEtoSQgrRTuw05TaMl9JwDe0RtBchCxK5sFRzdqw?key=QVpmemdBMHVXeVZIbUZodW4zLXF0M3NqV29rLTRR)

**NOTE: I do use android databinding and a viewpagaer. I'm not sure if this matters or not for my issue**.

In multiple awnsers I've seen people use:

```
 android:clipChildren="false"
 android:clipToPadding="false"
```

But even if I put that on all parents, it still happens. What am i doing wrong?

List Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //Adapter & recyclerview init
    mAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(productList, new     OnProductClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProductClick(View view1, Product product) {
            final View viewProductCv = view1.findViewById(R.id.list_product_cv);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductDetailPage.class);
            intent.putExtra(PRODUCT, product);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
                        Pair.create(viewProductCv, "productCardView")); // similar name
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            } else
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Recyclerview item layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <variable
        name="product"
        type="com.icemobile.estimotemirror.model.Product" />
</data>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_product_cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:transitionName="productCardView" <!-- similar name -->
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@{product.image}"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_product_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{product.name}"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_14" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_product_distance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{product.distance}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_12" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Activity details layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="product"
        type="com.icemobile.estimotemirror.model.Product" />
</data>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/details_card_view"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:transitionName="productCardView" <!-- similar name -->
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/list_product_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@{product.image, default=@drawable/default_thumbnail}"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="8dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/detail_product_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@{product.name}"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/title_18" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/detail_product_distance"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@{product.distance}"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_product_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/details_card_view"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="dedscription"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_14" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

My recyclerview Adapter:

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Product> productList;
private final OnProductClickListener listener;

public ProductListAdapter(List<Product> productList, OnProductClickListener listener) {
    this.productList = productList;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public ProductListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.list_item_product, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Product product = productList.get(position);
    viewHolder.bind(product, listener);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (productList != null) ? productList.size() : 0;
}

public void clear() {
    this.productList.clear();
}

public void add(Product product) {
    this.productList.add(product);
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ViewDataBinding binding;

    private ViewHolder(ViewDataBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    void bind(final Product product, final OnProductClickListener listener) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onProductClick(v, product);
            }
        });
        binding.setVariable(BR.product, product);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `it isn't fluid` isn't really giving us many details on the issue. Maybe you should add more content.

Comment: I edited it, but there is also a video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the childeren of the cardview that was used for shared element transition had a slightly different xml layout in the 2nd activity, that probably caused the stutter. Now I've kept the layout the same and the transition is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with data binding and recyclerviews.  The Data does not bind on the same frame as the viewholder, it waits a little bit. You need to make sure to add the following method when you use databinding in the recyclerview.adapter or viewholder so it binds immediately.

```
public void bind(Product product){
        mBinding.getViewModel().setProduct(product);
        mBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }
```

Comment: I already do that in my adapter. I've edited my post to show the recyclerview adapter